# Render each PdfPCell on new page

Tags: itext

I need to render each cell values in a new page.

I am using the following code :

```
List<string> values = getValues(); // getValues() method returns a list of strings
Document doc = new Document();
....
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
foreach(var s in values)
{
    table.AddCell(s);
    doc.NewPage();
}
...
```

But I am getting the output in a single page.

Comment: Just loop over each string and for each string: add it to a table THEN add it to the document THEN add a new page. You're adding cells to a table and then adding new pages, this won't work as you want it to, you'll need to add content to the document before adding pages unless you allow the document to have empty pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a one-cell table on each page:

```
List<string> values = getValues(); // getValues() method returns a list of strings
Document doc = new Document();
....
foreach(var s in values)
{
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.AddCell(s);
    doc.add(table);
    doc.NewPage();
}
...
```